# Python unittest ModuleImportFailure

Tags: python, unit-testing, module

I have the following structure:

```
project/
    survey/
        __init__.py
        survey_state_machine.py
    tests/
        survey/
            __init__.py
            test_survey_state_machine.py
```

Inside survey_state_machine.py, I define the classes SurveyState, SurveyStateService, SurveyCacheOperationException.

Inside test_survey.py I have the following import statements:

```
from survey.survey_state_machine import SurveyStateService
from survey.survey_state_machine import SurveyState
from survey.survey_state_machine import SurveyCacheOperationException
```

In "project" directory, I run:

```
python3 -m unittest discover tests/
```

And I receive:

```
ERROR: survey.test_survey_state_machine 
(unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
...
ImportError: No module named 'survey.survey_state_machine'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the import statement:
from project.survey import *

For more details and more understanding you can look onto the official  documentation page https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Please provide interpretation on the failures instead of just through-linking